# Is there anyway to show only hour and minutes in a UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

Is there anyway to show only hour and minutes in a UIDatePicker?

I've used

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
```

But it shows "PM" and "AM" too

Comment: Please actually ask a question in you question don't just leave it in the title.

Comment: Try setting the locale to a region that uses 24hour times: `[datePicker setLocale:locale];`

Comment: You can do magic with UIPicker, if you can't customize UIDatePicker

Comment: Try to create custom picker as your requirement .check this link for create custom picker http://code4app.net/category/picker

Comment: The appearance depends on the device locale, every user with locale where `hh` format is used should expect to see it like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to consider using setting the UIDatePickerMode to UIDatePickerModeCountdownTimer.  More info here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDatePickerMode

Note that just because the mode is called ...CountDownTimer does not mean that you have to use it only for counting down.

--Paul